# Php loop to retrieve all categories associated to each product

Tags: php, mysql, loops

After having spent hours trying to figure out how to create a useful loop so as to retrieve categories ids separated by commas I have decided to ask for help here hoping that someone would help. 
I have a table of categories with two columns products_id and category_id and I would like to get results like this:

Product_id 28 = category_ids) 403, 302, 391, 413

I have tried it in many different ways but I could not figure out how to make it work.

Please find attached a screen shot of the table I am using.
[image: Associated categories table]

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` in the MySQL query.

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(category_id)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. This was what I really needed. You have saved me a lot of time.